# How to send an email using wp_mail and using more than one BCC in the header

Tags: wp-mail

I have this code part that's responsible for getting the variables from the contact form - and and sending an email to me, and my friends from work.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_submit_contact_form', 'submit_contact_form'); 
// Send information from the contact form
function submit_contact_form(){

    // If there is a $_POST['email']...
    if( isset($_POST['email']) && ($_POST['validation'] == true ) ) {

        $email = $_POST['email'];       
        $email_to = "aaaa@example.pro";
        $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
        $headers = 'From: '. $fullname .' <'. $email .'>' . "\r\n";
        $group_emails = array(
            'bbb@example.com', 
            'ccc@example.com', 
            'ddd@example.com', 
            'eee@example.pro', 
            'fff@example.pro' 
            );
        $email_subject = "example intro: $email";
        $message = $_POST['text']; 

        if(wp_mail($group_emails,$email_subject,$message,$headers)) {
            echo json_encode(array("result"=>"complete"));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array("result"=>"mail_error"));
            var_dump($GLOBALS['phpmailer']->ErrorInfo);
    }
        wp_die();
    }
}
```

I want to add to the headers 4 emails as BCC.

How do I do this right?
I tried a few variations of writing it without any success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> > $headers can be a string or an array, but it may be easiest to use in
> >     the array form. To use it, push a string onto the array, starting with
> >     "From:", "Bcc:" or "Cc:" (note the use of the ":"), followed by a
> >     valid email address.
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail#Using_.24headers_To_Set_.22From:.22.2C_.22Cc:.22_and_.22Bcc:.22_Parameters

In other words:

```
$headers = array(
    'From: bbb@example.com', 
    'CC: ccc@example.com', 
    'CC: ddd@example.com', 
    'BCC: eee@example.pro', 
    'BCC: fff@example.pro' 
);
```

[You can see where the Core parses the string by splitting it on that ":"](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L296):

```
296  list( $name, $content ) = explode( ':', trim( $header ), 2 );
297 
298                                 // Cleanup crew
299                                 $name    = trim( $name    );
300                                 $content = trim( $content );
301 
302                                 switch ( strtolower( $name ) ) {
303                                         // Mainly for legacy -- process a From: header if it's there
304                                         case 'from':
```

Note: This is untested but I am fairly confident. I did not want to start sending email to addresses without warning (if those are even active addresses).

Comment: The only thing I changed for it to work is using $header and not $group_emails. 
TNX!

Comment: Can you post your final code? Help will be appreciated.

Comment: I note that wp_mail's processing of additional headers doesn't work exactly the same as the PHP mail() command. WP_MAIL uses additional headers in a one-dimensional array ("from:somebody@example.com"). The PHP mail() function allows for a two-dimensional array, as in $header = array("from" => "somebody@example.com"). If you supply a two-dimensional  additional headers array, wp_mail will not process the additional headers properly.